# Z3 low cpu usage

Tags: z3

I use z3 with .Net. The idle CPU usage on my system is around 1 to 10 %. When running Z3 i have abut 30% to 40% CPU usage (4 cores). I used Gurobi before and had most of the time 100% CPU usage there. 
Is there a way to configure z3 to use the cpu more heavily to get a solution quicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Z3 does not attempt to use all your cores. It runs by default on a single core.
Currently, the only supported way to leverage multiple cores within Z3 is by using tactics for spawning a portfolio search. Setting this up is somewhat advanced and not a common use.